# React Styled-Components CSS add !important to child elements

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a component that I would like to style with `!important` on some of the child elements.

Is it possible to use `&&&` to achieve this?

I've tried the following but it does not work:

```
const StyledTitle = styled(Title)`
  &&& span {
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
  }
  span &&& {
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
  }
`
```

Comment: What is your markup?

Comment: The nested elements are generated by an external script and have some inline styles applied that I want to override. I can see the react class is added correctly, I just can't get the `!important` added. I could write `!important` in the styled-component css above, but I would prefer not to if they have some syntax to do it automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are inline styles you are trying to override you will need to just add `!important`.  It boils down to CSS specificity - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

Inline styles have a high specificity score and are very difficult to override without using `!important`

The multiple `&` in styles components is used to raise the specificity but you'd have to abuse this in order to overrule the inline styles.